# Search and Replace a complex string in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, replace

I am working on a Client side where they have text like below saved into a MySQL Database, I need to delete it from all entries.

Using PHP or just SQL, can someone help me figure out how this can be done?  I have hundreds of records so manually editing each record isn't a viable solution.

The String of text will be like this below, where the text is different for each post record.

Another issue is there could be more then 1 per post record, so I need to simply find the 1st occurance of it and delete it.

```
<p><strong style="color: rgb(255, 127, 0); font-size: 20px;">
    This is my tile text here, I need to delete these?</strong></p>
```

Where * could be anything...

```
<p><strong style="color: rgb(255, 127, 0); font-size: 20px;">*</strong></p>
```

Comment: So you want to delete what exactly? The part inside the <p> tags or the whole field when this is found?

Comment: @migg I am hoping to remove this whole string when it's found in a larger `content` field...I'm doing this on a WordPress DB.  1 idea I have is using PHP, select the result and iterate each record running a REGEX on it, but I am not sure how the regex should be or if an easier way exists

Comment: "The whole string" is what?

Comment: @migg I am trying to delete this whole string `<p><strong style="color: rgb(255, 127, 0); font-size: 20px;">*</p>`

Answer (score 1):

```
$cleanstring = preg_replace(
    '#<p><strong style="color: rgb\(255, 127, 0\); font-size: 20px;">[^<]*</strong></p>#',
    '',
    $string,
    1
);
```

Comment: oh nice, I was thinking it would be some complex pattern, thanks

Comment: Problem with this pattern is its missing the delimiters and will if added replace anything between the open and the last closing </strong> tag

Comment: @migg Are you saying if there is multiple `<strong>` tags on the page it will capture everything in between the first open and the last closing one?

Comment: Now it stops at the first "<" instead.

Comment: not anymore after edit, but still missing the delimiters like # or /

Comment: @migg - what? can you explain more?